# Is it possible to validate deployed reports against DB schema?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Quite often we change DB schema, but forget (shame on us) to change queries of affected reports.

It would be nice if there were any way to turn on guard check of schema validity and all stored procedures and functions used in the reports.

Before we invest time in creating the script of that kind we'd like to know if that's possible with standard tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to run the procedure with "set noexec on":

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx

It should be quite straightforward to write a script that goes through all the procedures.

Comment: Probably, I don't understand correctly what you mean. What is the reason for noexec here? The idea is to get errors as early as possible.

Comment: With noexec you can "run" the procedure so that it is validated, but not actually executed, so you can also validate procedures that do inserts / updates / deletes.